# Visual Studio MySQL Database connection error

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio

I have been working on a secure login system for a school project. The system relies on a MySQL database to store user data. Passwords are stored as hashes and salts to make sure that the system is secure. I am working in Visual Studio 2010 with the 4.7 NET framework. I have downloaded the corresponding MySQL reference. The problem is that Visual Studio refuses to connect to my database and instead throws an "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts." exception. Here is my C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Secure_Login
{
    class UserData
    {
        //Variables
    public string userName;
    public string salt;
    public string hash;

    //Constructors
    public UserData()
    {

    }

    public UserData(string newName) 
    {
        userName = newName;
    }

    public UserData(string newName, string newSalt, string newhash)
    {
        userName = newName;
        salt = newSalt;
        hash = newhash;
    }

    //Methods
    public void SetUserName(string newName)
    {
        userName = newName;
    }

    public void SetSalt(string newSalt)
    {
        salt = newSalt;
    }

    public void SetHash(string newHash)
    {
        hash = newHash;
    }

    public void SetData(string newName, string newSalt, string newhash) 
    {
        userName = newName;
        salt = newSalt;
        hash = newhash;
    }

    public void GetData(string userName) 
    {
        MySqlConnection connection;
        //string connectionStringOriginal = "Server = myServerAddress; Database = myDataBase; Uid = myUsername; Pwd = myPassword;";
        string connectionString = "Server=sql202.epizy.com;Database=epiz_21820137_database;Uid=[My Username];Pwd=[My Password];";

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

        MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from TbUser WHERE UserName = @username";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", userName);

        connection.Open();

        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        hash = reader.GetString("hash");
        salt = reader.GetString("salt");

        connection.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

I hope that there is something wrong with my code and that it isn't the old version of Visual Studio that's screwing things up. Thanks in advance!

Greetings,

Thijs

Comment: It looks like you are trying to query and add the parameters (`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue...`), before you open the connection.

Comment: Can you try following the [standard format](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/), take note of the spacing and order.

Comment: @KaeL Adding to that, you might want to change `Pwd=[My Password];";` to `Pwd=[My Password]";` - you have a semi-colon too much within your password string

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'll try this as soon as possible.